# Using Symfony3 translator to provide email localized template file

Tags: php, symfony

I want to use symfony Translator to get twig template choosen by Locale which can by send by mailer to user.

I want to use something like:

```
$translator->trans('registration-mail'); //return transalted mail content
```

I want to use multiple files for locale, and for events like registration... etc.

The files will be stored in locale-specific folders:

```
/Resources/translation/emails/{LOCALE}/{EMAIL_TYPE}.html.twig
```

How can I do that?

I wrote own Loader, but its not works when I want use symfony translator. I set domain for `"emails"` in loader, create service with alias `html.twig`.

But it's looks like symfony doesn't seek for this files. Where I can told Symfony which files It should load with my Loader? How and Where to run it?